DiscordJS not responding to private messages
I'm working on a basic Discord bot to translate some private messages between participants. But for some reason, it won't react to private messages despite all my efforts:
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const { OpenAI } = require('openai');

const client = new Client({
    intents: ['Guilds','GuildMembers','GuildMessages','GuildMessageReactions','MessageContent','DirectMessages'],
    partials: ['Channel','Message']
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('The bot is online.');
});

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
    console.log('Message received');
});

The bot is coming online and responding the messages in public channels perfectly fine. But it keeps on ignoring private messages completely. Did my research on required Intents and perhaps even Partials, but it hasn't made any difference for me. Is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Have you enabled the required intents in the developer portal?

@RogueMan Yes, I did. If I launch the bot with DiscordPHP instead, it's working perfectly fine. Both DMs and public chat. It just won't work when launching with Discord.js. No errors, code is above, I really have no idea why it's not working

I have tried the code above in my bot and everything seems to be working fine.
My client intents and partials looks as follows:
const client = new Client({
intents: [IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent, IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages, IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds, IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers, IntentsBitField.Flags.DirectMessages],
partials: [Partials.Message, Partials.Channel],
});
